# UIView subview autolayout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have UITableView Cell in which 4 UIViews are arranged in a vertical order like this,

[image]

In each UIView, I have two Labels like this,

[image]

I have taken a IBOutlet for Height Constraint of all of the Four UIViews and I want to make the height 0 of the view when data is not available in that view. The problem is View is not getting 0 height due to the 10 px bottom constraint of UILabel inside that View.

What i am getting is like this,

[image]

**Code where constraints are handled**

```
    NSString *toName = [self jointNameFromArray:evidence.arrTo];
    if ([Utility isEmptyString:toName]) {
        cell.toViewHeight.constant = 0;
    }
    else {
        cell.lblToName.text = toName;
    }

    NSString *fromName = [self jointNameFromArray:evidence.arrFrom];
    if ([Utility isEmptyString:fromName]) {
        cell.fromViewHeight.constant = 0;
    }
    else {
        cell.lblFromName.text = fromName;
    }

    NSString *ccName = [self jointNameFromArray:evidence.arrCc];
    if ([Utility isEmptyString:ccName]) {
        cell.ccViewHeight.constant = 0;
    }
    else {
        cell.lblCCName.text = ccName;
    }

    NSString *custName = [self jointNameFromArray:evidence.arrCustodian];
    if ([Utility isEmptyString:custName]) {
        cell.custViewHeight.constant = 0;
    }
    else {
        cell.lblCustName.text = custName;
    }    
     [cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: do you want to hide the To label too ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes

Comment: when you change a constraint you need to call the layoutIfNeeded method.

Comment: instead of giving two height constraints for two labels, give the uiview height constraint to 0 and call layout if needed.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes I have taken IBOutlet for Height of UIView and changing it to 0 when no data available. And I have tried layoutIfNeeded too  but no luck. I am doing this in cellForRow method.

Comment: and then did u call the layoutIfneeded method ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes. Only problem is the bottom constraint of UILabel is not letting UIView to be 0 height

Comment: pls post code of how and where ur changing the constraints

Comment: @TejaNandamuri http://pastebin.com/xREApQ86

Comment: take a look at Stack View

Comment: take height and top constraint **IBOUTLET** and when you don't want to show your label set height constant = 0 and also top constant = 0 also.. will help

Comment: have you tried to switch the table cell's _Clip Subview_ property __on__ in IB? or have you just dynamically changed the number of the cells regarding to wether there is data to show? this latest would be more reasonable in my view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting iOS 9+, I'd suggesting using `UIStackView`, as it does exactly what you want just by setting the `.hidden` property of your view to `true`.

https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/04/uistackview/

If you are unable to use `UIStackView`, you will need to set one of the vertical padding constraints to a lower priority than the height constraint. You will also need to set `.clipsToBounds` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Set constraint programatically and write logic as u want it is good idea and dont forgot to  set layoutifnedded.